# asp.net - override configuration-based impersonation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, impersonation

I have an asp.net web api project that uses impersonation via a web config element to connect to our SQL databases:

```
<identity impersonate="true"
      userName="domain\user1" 
      password="password" />
```

This works perfectly in 99.9% of cases. However, there is one specific endpoint that requires additional privileges in SQL server. I would like to impersonate a second user, let's call it user2, instead of user1 for this specific call, and then revert back to user1 for all other requests. I believe impersonation can be implemented programmatically, but can it be used alongside the configuration-based approach above so that I can programmatically override (and subsequently revert to default) the impersonated user for this one endpoint?

Comment: An unrelated question: why you need impersonation at all? Why don't you just set the app pool's identity to this user?

Comment: If this one operation is something the user can do whenever they want, grant them the rights to do it with their own account. If it's something that requires some form of limiting / gate keeping then the user shouldn't be making changes to data directly. Create a service/process that is responsible for making that change and allow the user to connect to it. That way, the new process runs with more creds but is specifically designed to limit access to certain specific situations

Answer (score 0):

Use connection strings in your web.config.

If you can use standard security, reference that. If you can only use integrated, create a DSN with the credentials and reference the DSN in the connection string element.

In the second endpoint, reference the second connection string that has elevated privileges. This will give the API a lot more flexibility in case a future endpoint requires different privileges.

Comment: Both are valid options but would a connection string approach would require touching a lot of existing code, which is not ideal. It may be necessary if there are no alternatives